# Binding get and set property in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, binding, angular

I have get and set properties named `position`. I have a position saved in a variable `positionInPerc` that has position stored in percentage(%) and it has a default some default value. By position I mean the position of a div. `get position` will take value from `positionInPerc` and convert the position from percentage to pixel and return it. `set position` will take value in pixel and convert it to % and set the value to variable `positionInPerc`.

Code :

In component -

```
private positionInPerc:number;
public get position() : number {
    return this.Helper.convertFromPercToPx(this.positionInPerc);
}
public set position(value){
    var converted = this.Helper.convertFromPxToPerc(value);
    this.positionInPerc = converted;
}
```

And in HTML -

```
<div [style.top.px]="position"> Hello </div>
```

Problem is that `get position` is called initially. But set is not called when the position of the div is changed. div's position is changed by dragging the element. Is it supported in Angular 2? If not, is there any other way I can achieve this?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: post code for `this.Helper.convertFromPercToPx` and what do you mean by `I am changing div's position by dragging the element` ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I mean div is draggable and it's position changes when it is dragged. I want that whenever div is dragged, the new top position is set automatically

Comment: How Pardeep said, we don't see where the **set position** is called. You need to post more code, or better create a plunker.

Comment: I figured this out. There's no straight way, so I am now changing value by listening to drag event of the div.